# Word Count only for certain sections

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get a word count from a text file. That part is relatively easy. My difficulty is, the file is a transcript where each speaker may speak a varying number of lines and I want to get the word count for only Speaker 1. Fortunately, each time a new speaker begins, we have their name and a colon. Example below:

Speaker 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in tincidunt erat. Nulla ac ipsum id est cursus venenatis eget nec velit. Nulla sollicitudin sed nulla et aliquet. In ex augue, tincidunt id lacus vel, feugiat rhoncus nisl. Phasellus in lectus scelerisque, finibus sapien vel, ornare ex. Proin faucibus eleifend volutpat. Vivamus maximus risus a nulla vulputate gravida vitae consequat ante. Duis malesuada blandit tortor, sed efficitur leo porta vel. In quam mi, congue in auctor sed, elementum nec ex. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed hendrerit elit ac justo rutrum sagittis. 
Speaker 2: Sed at aliquam nibh. Nunc laoreet orci risus, vitae ornare elit tempus eget. 
Speaker 1: roin massa ante, condimentum ornare justo nec, vehicula gravida diam. Ut nibh metus, aliquam sit amet consequat at, vulputate a magna.

I am trying to get a word count for only Speaker 1. As you can see, each speaker may speak only 1 sentence, or may speak several. Here is the code I'm using to get the word count. I'm only interested in words longer than 3 letters.

```
import string
fhand = open('transcript.txt')
counts = dict()
for line in fhand:
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if len(word) < 4: continue
        else:
            if word not in counts:
                counts[word] = 1
            else:
                counts[word] += 1

# Sort the dictionary by value
lst = list()
for key, val in list(counts.items()):
    lst.append((val, key))

lst.sort(reverse=True)

for key, val in lst[:100]
    print(val,key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the whole file into a string:

```
with open('transcript.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()
```

Then get only the portion relevant for speaker 1:

```
b = [i for i in a.split('Speaker ') if i.startswith('1:')]
```

Replace the 1:'s from the strings:

```
c = ''.join(b).replace('1:', '')
```

Use Counter to get the dictionary of word count:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(c.split())
```

It will give you something like this

```
Counter({'Duis': 1,
     'In': 2,
     'Lorem': 1,
     'Nulla': 2,
     'Orci': 1,
     'Phasellus': 1,
     'Praesent': 1,
     'Proin': 1,
     'Sed': 1, ....
```

Modification for specific speaker name: 
Suppose, you have the following string:

```
'JIM: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in tincidunt erat. Nulla ac ipsum id est cursus venenatis eget nec velit. Nulla sollicitudin sed nulla et aliquet. In ex augue, tincidunt id lacus vel, feugiat rhoncus nisl. Phasellus in lectus scelerisque, finibus sapien vel, ornare ex. Proin faucibus eleifend volutpat. Vivamus maximus risus a nulla vulputate gravida vitae consequat ante. Duis malesuada blandit tortor, sed efficitur leo porta vel. In quam mi, congue in auctor sed, elementum nec ex. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed hendrerit elit ac justo rutrum sagittis. JEFF: Sed at aliquam nibh. Nunc laoreet orci risus, vitae ornare elit tempus eget. JIM: roin massa ante, condimentum ornare justo nec, vehicula gravida diam. Ut nibh metus, aliquam sit amet consequat at, vulputate a magna.\n'
```

This following function will take the string as a first argument and name as the second argument:

```
def get_word_count(S, N):
    w = []
    a = False
    for i in S.split():
        if i == N:
             a = True
        if i != N and ':' in i:
             a = False
        if a:
             w += [i]
    return Counter(w)
```

Now, if you want to get word count for 'JIM', use

```
JIM = get_word_count(a, 'JIM:')
```

for 'JEFF':

```
JEFF = get_word_count(a, 'JEFF:')
```

Comment: Hi mamun - I thought this solution worked at first, but it doesn't :( I'm sorry if I'm implementing it incorrectly. It gives me a count of every item in the list regardless of whether or not it is prefaced by Speaker 1: or Speaker 2: Also, and this is completely my fault and not yours, my actual transcript has names JIM: and JEFF: as well as 30 other speakers. Is there a way to get those names not to show up? Sorry, I thought this worked at first.

Comment: Thanks again mamun; This did the trick exactly. Appreciate the patience and expertise!

Answer (score 1):

for example if you just want to count the words by `JIM` then you can do:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
with open('transcript.txt', 'r') as fhand:
    words = Counter(re.sub(r'\w+(?<!JIM):(?:(?!JIM:).)*|JIM:','',fhand).split())

print(words)
```

for the others, Just change the name as you want.

You can write a function:

```
get_count = lambda x,Name: Counter(re.sub(r'\w+(?<!'+Name+'):(?:(?!'+Name+':).)*|'+Name+':','',x).split())
```

Now run:

```
fhand = open('transcript.txt','r')

get_count(fhand,'JIM')
```

Comment: This is better.